# Can't connect to remote MySQL server on RHEL from local Windows

Tags: mysql

I have installed XAMPP in a remote RHEL machine. Let's say the IP address of this machine is 10.120.42.70. I have configured the file `/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf` for remote access and have moved this file to `/etc/my.cnf` so that the settings in this file are now the global options for mysql server.

Here is my `/etc/my.cnf` file

```
# Example MySQL config file for medium systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (32M - 64M) where MySQL plays
# an important part, or systems up to 128M where MySQL is used together with
# other programs (such as a web server)
#
# You can copy this file to
# /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is /opt/lampp/var/mysql) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

# Here follows entries for some specific programs

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
user = mysql
port=3306
socket      = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
#skip-external-locking
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
bind-address = 0.0.0.0


# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir = /opt/lampp/lib/mysql/plugin/

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by xampp security


# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   = 1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir     = /tmp/     
#log-update     = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /opt/lampp/var/mysql/
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
# Deprecated in 5.6
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout

!include /opt/lampp/mysql/my.cnf
```

You can see that the `skip-external-locking` is commented out and there is no `skip-networking` line. The `bind-address` is set to `0.0.0.0` so that the server will accept connections from any IP address.

I am able to login to MySQL server using this from within the RHEL machine

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
mysql -h 10.120.42.70 -u root -p
```

Both of the above commands works fine and enables me to login to server

When I try to connect to the server from my local Windows machine like this:

```
 mysql -h 10.120.42.70 -u root -p
```

It asks for password and I give the password, but I am getting the error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.120.42.70'
>   (10060 "Unknown error")

I have granted the privileges for the user `root'. Still I am getting the same error.

In my RHEL remote machine, I run `netstat` and I get this:

```
  sudo netstat -lntp | grep 3306
  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      16323/mysqld
```

So the mysql server is definitely listening on 3306 to all IP addresses. I wonder why I am still not able to access it remotely.

Comment: did you get this resolved as it sounds similar to the problem i am having?

Answer (score 1):

Did you grant the privileges for the user 'root'@'localhost'? If so, try to grant them to 'root'@'%'.
MySQL identifies a user with it's username and hostname. If connecting from a different machine, your root user would be identified as root@somehost instead of root@localhost.

Comment: This answer does not apply to OP's problem. `Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.120.42.70'` means network related problem. For your case it would say something about permissions.

Comment: I did. This is the SQL query I used and it executed without any error
          GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword'